# Инициализация внутри определения функции парараметра с типом IN

Tags: oracle, plsql

Часто вижу в примерах присвоение параметру типа `IN`:

```
Create or replace function atr (sode in number, code in number :=1000) return varchar2
```

Зачем нужно присваивать заранее известное значение в функциях?

Ниже идёт оператор ветвления:

```
If code in  (1000,2000)
```

Соответвенно, зачем проверять известное присвоенное значение на соответствие?

Comment: А что вы понимаете под  _заранее известное_? Присваивается значение по умолчанию, поэтому вопрос не совсем понятен.

Comment: Понял, если в параметр не будет передано значение то в параметр будет равен 1000. Я так предположил что это заранее известное, поскольку не знал что такая запись означает значение по умолчанию.

Comment: А предложенный ответ действительно помог, или остались вопросы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение по-умолчанию в функции используется:

- Для написания более лаконичного кода. Если функция 100 раз вызывается так:

  ```
  atr (1)
  ```

  и, например, есть только один специальный случай с отличаюшимся значением:

  ```
  atr (1, code=>3000)
  ```
- Для "безболезненного" изменения/расширения функции. Например, добавив новый параметр `code in number :=1000`, существуюший код в местах вызова функции останется без изменений. Без значения по-умолчанию для нового параметра, надо  будет добавить его всюду, где функция вызывaется (десятки, а то и сотни изменений).

  ```
  create or replace function atr (sode in number) return varchar2 is
  begin
      return 'старое значение для '||sode; 
  end;
  /
  ```

  Так было, а через пару лет решили изменить, добавив новый параметр:

  ```
  create or replace function atr (sode in number, code in number:=1000) return varchar2 is
  begin
      return case 
          when code != 1000 then 
               'значение для '||sode||' с учетом code '||code 
          else 'старое значение для '||sode end;
  end;
  /
  select atr (99) result from dual
  /
  RESULT
  --------------------------------
  старое значение для 99
  ```